# Recurring baby mobile in multiple episodes of Doctor Who

Tags: doctor-who

In the 11th Doctor episode [Amy's Choice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1591788/), Amy is made to think she is having a baby. In the upper room where

> Rory dies

there is a baby's crib mobile above it. The camera seems to focus on it for a bit.

I don't know if it appeared again before [Day of the Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1723889/), but the same mobile is in the room where Amy sees the picture of her with a baby. Also in [Curse of the Black Spot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1721225/) there seems to be a mobile in that episode.

Does anyone know yet if this is a coincidence or if they are trying to allude to something?

Please note that answers should be designed to be timeless - please avoid referring to "the latest episode" or "today's episode" (use the episode name instead).  Please also avoid pure speculation, and give answers that are based on evidence from the show.  Finally, please only give answers that are specifically about the mobile (e.g. avoid answers that just speculate about Amy's pregnancy).

Comment: I hardly think that's a spoiler.

Answer (score 5):

Have you been watching Season 6?  They're probably trying to allude to something, but they haven't revealed it yet.  I expect the Season 6

> 'is Amy pregnant or not?'

plot thread pay off to address the mobile.